# Resampling pandas columns datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

(I think) I have a dataset with the columns representing `datetime` intervals

Columns were transformed in datetime with:

```
    for col in df.columns:
        df.rename({col: pd.to_datetime(col, infer_datetime_format=True)}, inplace=True)
```

Then, I need to `resample` the columns (year and month '2001-01') into quarters using `mean`

I tried

```
df = df.resample('1q', how='mean', axis=1)
```

The `DataFrame` also has a multindex set `['RegionName', 'County']`

But I get the error:

```
Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

Is the problem in the `to_datetime` function or in the wrong sampling?

Comment: Can you post the first few rows of your dataframe? The `df.rename` statement should fail based on the information you have given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I think) you are renaming each column head rather than making the entire columns object a `DatetimeIndex`

Try this instead:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
```

Then run your `resample`

---

***note:***
I'd do it with `period` after converting to `DatetimeIndex`.  That way, you get the period in your column header rather than an end date of the quarter.

```
df.groupby(df.columns.to_period('Q'), axis=1).mean()
```

***demo***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(2, -1),
                  columns=['2011-01-31', '2011-02-28', '2011-03-31',
                           '2011-04-30', '2011-05-31', '2011-06-30'])

df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)

print(df.groupby(df.columns.to_period('Q'), axis=1).mean())

   2011Q1  2011Q2
0       1       4
1       7      10
```

Comment: But the value of the columns is another information (price - which I want the mean over the three months(three columns). I actually want the heads as DateTime so that I can aggregate the months into quarters.